# Custom Wikipedia search to retrieve only summary (JavaScript?)

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to implement 2 things on my website, that i know that are possible sepparetly, but combined.
First, a custom search box to retrieve results within the site without getting to wikipedia.
Second, to just retrieve the summary of the articles so i get a reasonable ammount of data to fit in a short space.
I mean. I want a searchbox that returns not entire articles, just the summaries or abstracts, in a little  element within my website.

Demos for both things can be found in this article: 
http://www.golygon.com/2011/01/addingcustomizing-wikipedia-search-in-your-website/

Of course I'd like to style everything at will....

I haven't found an example to combine both tasks. And since I don't get how the wikpedia API works at all, i was hoping you could help me please.

I only have a very basic skills using javascript... so if theres a way to doing it only with javascript, that'd be great.

I Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone???? any ideas???? please??? I feel so close.....

Comment: You could use the abstracts dumps from http://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html , e.g. http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20140102/enwiki-20140102-abstract.xml

Answer (score 1):

The API call you want to use is `query&prop=extracts`. Then you can chose formatting, length and so on. `titles` is what they search for.
Example (with a limit of three sentences and one search result): 
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exsentences=3&exlimit=1&titles=Stack%20Exchange